# Redis - Alternative to check existence of multiple values in a set

Tags: java, redis

In my application I need have a set of values and I need to check how many of these values are present in a **set in Redis**.

Just to make it simple, What I want to do is something like :

```
> Sadd myset field1
(integer) 1
> Sadd myset field2
(integer) 1
> Sadd myset field4
(integer) 1

> Sismember myset field1 field4 // which is not possible as of now.
```

Since I can not give multiple parameters for `SISMEMBER`, I might have to multiple redis call which is very time consuming.

I was thinking about alternatives like `pipelining` but then I thought this will be a good (hacky) way of achieving it :

```
> Hset myhash field1 "true"
(integer) 0
> Hset myhash field2 "true"
(integer) 0
> Hset myhash field4 "true"
(integer) 1

> Hmget myhash field1 field2 field3
1) "true"
2) "true"
3) (nil)

> Hmget myhash field1 field2 field3 field4
1) "true"
2) "true"
3) (nil)
4) "true"
```

`Redis` [HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/hmget) page says the following :

> Available since 2.0.0.
>
> Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of fields being requested.

Which is really good when compared to making multiples calls for `SADD`, But I am really not sure If I am 100% correct and I also don't know if there is any serious drawback of using `hmget` this way.

So I just wanted to the drawbacks of using `hmget` this way and any better approaches to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly a valid solution, although a little wasteful as you'll be maintaining a bunch of `true` values - a RAM overhead. FYI, Redis' Sets are implemented internally using the same hash table structs as Hashes are, so you're not that far off :)

While there is no variadic form of `SISMEMBER`, it as an easily scriptable flow with Lua so you may want to consider that as well. For example something like the following:

```
local r = {}

for _, m in pairs(ARGV) do
  r[#r+1] = redis.call('SISMEMBER', KEYS[1], m)
end

return r
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I won't be able to do this programatically right? (I actually want to do this from `Java`)

Comment: Sure you can - Redis' Lua scripts can be invoked from Java perfectly fine. Read the your client's (Jedis?) docs.

Comment: Yes, Jedis. Actually I am using Spring Data Redis. I will check how to do this.

Comment: Thank you :) I was able to run run the lua script. This is the first time I heard the name `lua`, so I could not exactly understand your script. I searched a bit and wrote a little bit different script based on your script. Please have a look and let me know if that works in all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Following @itamar 's answer, I was able to do this using lua script.

I used the following script:

```
 local r = {}
 for i, m in pairs(KEYS) do
    r[i] = redis.call('SISMEMBER',ARGV[1],m)
 end
 return r
```

May be this will be useful for someone in future, so just writing how to call this script from `java` (`Spring Data Redis 1.5.0` & `jedis 2.6.2`)

```
    redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("mySet","3");
    redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("mySet","4");
    redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("mySet","35");
    redisTemplate.opsForSet().add("mySet", "6");
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("1"); 
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("35");
    list.add("6");
    System.out.println(redisTemplate.execute(script, list,"mySet"));
```

prints the following :

```
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

**EDIT** I am not sure everybody is saying that `mySet` is KEYS and `list` is ARGV, but in `SPRING DATA REDIS`, `execute` function is defined in the following way :

```
public <T> T execute(RedisScript<T> script, List<K> keys, Object... args) {
    return this.scriptExecutor.execute(script, keys, args);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this works for you - you're looping on KEYS, but it had just one element in the array (`mySet`)...

Comment: @ItamarHaber execute function takes `List of Keys` and then arguments. May be this is specific to `Spring Data Redis`, I did not try with `Jedis` directly. (`mySet` is the set name)

Comment: That is the regular behaviour - I'm referring to your Lua that does a `for` loop on the single key that you provide the script.

Comment: Your KEYS and ARGV are mixed up. `mySet` is a KEY, and `list` contains your ARGV.

Comment: @OfirLuzon I debugged line by line and wrote this. `list` is KEYS and `mySet` is ARGV. (at least in `Spring Data Redis`)

Comment: Yes, but list is not a Redis KEY while mySet is.
It does work the way you wrote it, but you should consider using KEYS with Redis keys and ARGV for anything else.

Comment: @OfirLuzon ah! Now I understand what you were saying. I will read about `lua` more and follow conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is much easier way to do it on Java with [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework:

```
RSet<String> set = redisson.getSet("mySet");

// uses lua-script under the hood
if (set.containsAll(Arrays.asList("obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4"))) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Redis 6.2 you can use [SMISMEMBER](https://redis.io/commands/smismember) command check the existence of multiple element is the given set. It will return the array reply of the elements given in the same order as they are requested. You can get the sum of the array on the client side to get how many of these values are present in the set.

```
redis> SADD myset foo bar zet que
(integer) 4
redis> SMISMEMBER myset foo bar not
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 1
3) (integer) 0
```